# How to bring up PDF embedded in windows.forms.webbrowser control in VISTA

Tags: vb.net, pdf, windows-vista, browser, webbrowser-control

```
Webbrowser1.Navigate("http://mysite.com/test.pdf")
```

XP WEBBROWSER-CONTROL: brings up PDF embedded in webbrowser control, as desired.

XP IE7:  Behaves the same if you manually navigate to URL, as desired.

VISTA WEBBROWSER-CONTROL: brings up PDF by separately launching Acrobat, won't embed in webbrowser control.  Not desired.

Vista IE7: embeds PDF properly if you navigate to same URL, as desired.

I am using Acrobat 9, where there is a preference setting under Internet to bring up PDF embedded in browser -- works fine directly in IE7, but not in webbrowser control.

I want the PDF to come up in the webbrowser control in Vista same as it does on XP and Vista IE7.

I have looked at every property/method/event in webbrowser control and can't find any settings that would matter.  I have tried to find some Vista setting that would be relevant, can't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Platform Target = x86 as to be set.  Found answer here:
[link text](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/1a9c8004-a63e-4ac9-b466-3dbfb4c9c540)

Answer (score 0):

I am using "URL Parameters" as in [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) to get to a certain PDF Page or bookmark. There is something for the layout too. Fineprint: I also do have some issue ([see Fragment lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033589/fragment-anchor-in-net-4-webbrowser-control-getting-lost-with-adobe-pdf-read)) using it with the WinForm WebBrowser control, nevertheless I find the approach useful (for me it works on Win 7 with .NET 4 except the mentioned issue).